# Different frames displayed on one frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a multiple page app but have troubles with raising different frames above another. I have followed sentdex's tutorials on this and tried a lot of different approaches but have a problem with all frame widgets being displayed on the same frame, not on different frames as I wanted.

The button and "Start page text" should be on the first frame and once I press the button I should invoke another frame to be raised above this one. The second frame's text ("Question page text") should let you know you are on another frame.

This does not happen. Both texts as well as the button are displayed on the same frame.

You can run the code bellow to see what I mean.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class Quiz(Tk):
    frames = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = Frame(self, height=50, width=90)
        self.frames.append(container)
        container.pack()

        self.show_frame(StartPage(container, self))

    def show_subject(self):
        container = self.frames[0]
        self.show_frame(self, Question(container, self))

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        text = Text(width=40, height=2, spacing1=15)
        text.insert(INSERT, "Start page text")
        text.pack()

        button = ttk.Button(text="Geo", command=Quiz.show_subject(Quiz)).pack(fill=X)


class Question(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        text = Text(width=40, height=2, spacing1=15)
        text.insert(INSERT, "Question page text")
        text.pack()


app = Quiz()
app.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated because I have been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the cornerstones of the design you are copying is that everything within a page should be a child of that page. That's the whole point -- each "page" is treated as a self-contained widget. You aren't doing that.

If you want something to appear on a specific page, make it part of the page. If it's supposed to be visible globally, don't put it on one of the pages. Instead, stick it in the root window.

Comment: I see. I am still not sure where I should put the widgets of each frame. When putting it on the container it puts everything on the same frame, but if I try to put them on that particular frame - self, I get a blank window. If I try to set widget's master as self's parent - superclass Frame, I get an error saying self has no parent. How should I access the root window? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! I wasn't placing the frames in the grid, now there is no problem with using self as the master :)